# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, typeerror

Keep getting this error, no idea why

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

My code is:

```
function write(message) {
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += message + '<br/>';
}

function calculateCircumference (diameter) {
    return diameter * 3.14;
}

write (calculateCircumference(4));
```

Comment: Can you show your `html` as well?

Comment: It simply means that your code is getting `null` back from the `getElementById()` call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Admittedly, the error message is not exactly transparent as to its meaning (but at least you get an error - jQuery would just silently do nothing!)

What it means is that the result of `document.getElementById('message')` is null. [Looking at the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) you will find that this happens when the element cannot be found.

The main reason for an element not being found is because it doesn't exist yet.

```
<script>// do something with document.getElementById('message');</script>
<div id="message"></div>
```

The above will FAIL because `message` does not exist yet. Moving the script after the div will make it work.

Side-note: 3.14 is far too inaccurate. Use `Math.PI` instead, it's as accurate as a number in JavaScript can be.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your code is executed before the DOM is ready

```
window.onload = function(){
    function write(message) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += message + '<br/>';
    }

   function calculateCircumference (diameter) {
        return diameter * 3.14;
    }

    write (calculateCircumference(4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your id is set and you still get the same error, make sure you have done the opening and closing tags of your html correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused when the element is not loaded and the js function is trying to access it.

> try adding the `<script>` tag at the very end of the document before `</body>`

or check if the name of the element is mistyped.